# Кодировка символов

Tags: php

Что бы из базы выводило без иероглифов добавил:

```
 mysqli_query ($db, 'set character_set_results = "utf8"');
```

Вот само подключение к бд:

```
$db = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "stretchc_admin", "5616456164", "stretchc_db");
```

Все работает но выводятся ошибки:

**Notice: Undefined variable: db in /home/stretchc/public_html/resources/php/db.php on line 2**

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/stretchc/public_html/resources/php/db.php on line 2**

Как избавиться от ошибок?

Comment: mysqli_query() у вас как раз в db.php и на второй строке?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Она идет перед дб так как если поставить после то показываются иероглифы

Comment: серьезно? вы даете на вход `null` и все работает? Магия

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, проблем с выводом нету, но если поставить после объявления то есть
http://stretch-ceilings.by/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вместо своего варианта воткнуть в начало файла

```
mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Всё гуд но появилось вот это:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/stretchc/public_html/resources/php/db.php on line 2

Comment: Всё та же ошибка

Comment: Странно, ошибка в том, что mysqli_query ожидает 2 параметра, но у вас их и так 2. Может у вас неподходящая версия php или mysql?

Comment: Нет, может быть дело в том что я устанавливаю кодировку раньше чем устанавливаю соединение с бд в переменной, но иначе не срабатывает, показывает иероглифы

Comment: Решили проблему? Каким образом? Вы бы проверили еще кодировку своей базы, таблицы, полей таблицы. Она должна быть везде одинаковая.

Comment: А еще в php.ini тоже стоит глянуть

Comment: Она везде одинаковая, эта проблема появилась только в тех элементах которые я подгружаю через ajax запрос